# Calculate number of watches by number of users in sql

Tags: sql

I want to write 1 query that calculates the frequency buckets for each Ad.  The frequency buckets would be the number of users who watched the Ad 1 time, 2 times, 3 times, etc. The table is:

| AdId | UserID | Watch Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | 1/22 |
| 123 | B | 1/13 |
| 123 | C | 1/22 |
| 123 | A | 1/24 |
| 123 | A | 1/11 |
| 123 | B | 1/10 |
| 123 | D | 1/14 |
| 123 | E | 1/20 |

The output I'm looking for is this: 3 users(C, D, E) watched the ad once, 1 user(B) watched it twice and 1 user(A) watched it 3 times.

| AdId | # of Times Watched | # of Users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |

I have tried using count and group by but that does not give me this result

Comment: i really can't understand how you come for table 1 to the result table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select   max(AdId)              as AdId
        ,cnt                    as '# of Times Watched'
        ,count(distinct UserID) as '# of Users'
from     (
          select  *
                 ,count(*) over(partition by AdId, UserID) as cnt
          from    t
         ) t
group by cnt
```

| AdId | # of Times Watched | # of Users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 3 |
| 123 | 2 | 1 |
| 123 | 3 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YcJaJ6jw?hide=4)